# Stopping application when all threads are died

Tags: java, multithreading

In my java application I have many threads, but there are several most important threads, which do complex calculations (accessing remote db's, etc).

In case **all** these important threads are `died`, then I need to quit the application, even less important threads still are running.

I implemented an additional (thread) class to monitor these threads with core functionality like this:

```
   boolean allThreadsDied;
   do {
      allThreadsDied = true;
      for (Thread oneThread : threadsList) {
         allThreadsDied = allThreadsDied & (!oneThread.isAlive());
      }
   } while (!allThreadsDied);

   // now, it's time to quit the application
```

This thread runs permanently and checks the state of important threads.

I think I have invented *a bicycle*, and very non-efficient bicycle. Because this thread, running permanently, produces high processor load, even when there are no current calculations.

My question is as follows: is there a more efficient way to monitor a group of threads and get a signal when all these threads are died ?

Comment: how about activating the thread every second, and letting it sleep otherwise?

Comment: If you just want to shutdown the JVM when only "minor" threads remain, you could make those daemon threads. There is a flag in the Thread class for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark all non-important threads as `daemon` threads (see: [`Thread.setDaemon()`](http://java.xiruibin.com/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29)) and start all important ones normally.

Once all non-daemon threads are dead/done, the JVM quits automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Thread.join`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) like this:

```
for (Thread t : threadsList) {
    t.join();
}
```

Let's say you put this code at the end of your `main` method. Calling `t.join()` will cause the main thread to wait until thread `t` has died.

Answer (score 1):

Change that whole thing to:

```
for (Thread oneThread : threadsList) {
   try {
      oneThread.join();
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // handle this
   }
}
```

This will wait for each of the threads to finish their processing, but not waste CPU cycles. (The thread running this will sleep during the `join`.)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a thread you can specify whether it is a "daemon" thread or not. When `main()` returns the application will continue running if there are any non-daemon threads running, however it will not continue running if only daemon threads remain. When you spawn your non-important thread you can spawn them as daemon threads which may achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an answer to your problem: threads can be flagged as daemons. A daemon thread will not prevent the JVM from shutting down. So in your case, keep the worker threads "as is" and the less important threads as daemon with the `thread.setDaemon(true)` method.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the application quits automatically. Whatever:

```
System.exit(0); // forces the app to exit.
```